# Python numpy matrix multiplication with one diagonal matrix

Tags: numpy, matrix-multiplication

I have two arrays A (4000,4000) of which only the diagonal is filled with data, and B (4000,5), filled with data. Is there a way to multiply (dot) these arrays that is faster than the numpy.dot(a,b) function?

So far I found that `(A * B.T).T` should be faster (where A is one dimensional (4000,), filled with the diagonal elements), but it turned out to be roughly twice as slow.

is there a faster way to calculate B.dot(A) in the case where A is a diagnal array?

Comment: Are those arrays or matrices? Also, are you sure about (B * A.T).T?

Comment: Numpy Matrices, I did the testing for (B*A.T).T, but only for a small matrix, so I will try it for a big matrix and post the results

Comment: I mean for A (4000,5),  B (4000,4000), you would have misalignement error for `B * A.T`.

Comment: Again after the edits, `(A * B.T).T` won't work and again because of shape misalignment.

Comment: Yes, but in that case A would be a 1D (4000,) array

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could simply extract the diagonal elements and then perform broadcasted elementwise multiplication.

Thus, a replacement for `B*A` would be -

```
np.multiply(np.diag(B)[:,None], A)
```

and for `A.T*B` -

```
np.multiply(A.T,np.diag(B))
```

Runtime test -

```
In [273]: # Setup
     ...: M,N = 4000,5
     ...: A = np.random.randint(0,9,(M,N)).astype(float)
     ...: B = np.zeros((M,M),dtype=float)
     ...: np.fill_diagonal(B, np.random.randint(11,99,(M)))
     ...: A = np.matrix(A)
     ...: B = np.matrix(B)
     ...: 

In [274]: np.allclose(B*A, np.multiply(np.diag(B)[:,None], A))
Out[274]: True

In [275]: %timeit B*A
10 loops, best of 3: 32.1 ms per loop

In [276]: %timeit np.multiply(np.diag(B)[:,None], A)
10000 loops, best of 3: 33 µs per loop

In [282]: np.allclose(A.T*B, np.multiply(A.T,np.diag(B)))
Out[282]: True

In [283]: %timeit A.T*B
10 loops, best of 3: 24.1 ms per loop

In [284]: %timeit np.multiply(A.T,np.diag(B))
10000 loops, best of 3: 36.2 µs per loop
```

Comment: Nice. the `np.multiply(np.diag(B)[:,None], A)` works only if `B` is a diagonal matrix right? And `A` can be a matrix or vector.

Answer (score 0):

Appears that my initial claim of (A * B.T).T being slower is incorrect.

```
from timeit import default_timer as timer
import numpy as np

##### Case 1
a = np.zeros((4000,4000))
np.fill_diagonal(a, 10)
b = np.ones((4000,5))

dot_list = []

def time_dot(a,b):
    start = timer()
    c = np.dot(a,b)
    end = timer()
    return end - start

for i in range(100):
    dot_list.append(time_dot(a,b))

print np.mean(np.asarray(dot_list))

##### Case 2
a = np.ones((4000,))
a = a * 10
b = np.ones((4000,5))

shortcut_list = []

def time_quicker(a,b):
    start = timer()
    c = (a*b.T).T
    end = timer()
    return end - start

for i in range(100):
    shortcut_list.append(time_quicker(a,b))

print np.mean(np.asarray(shortcut_list))


##### Case 3
a = np.zeros((4000,4000)) #diagonal matrix
np.fill_diagonal(a, 10)
b = np.ones((4000,5))

case3_list = []

def function(a,b):
    start = timer()
    np.multiply(b.T,np.diag(a))
    end = timer()
    return end - start

for i in range(100):
    case3_list.append(function(a,b))

print np.mean(np.asarray(case3_list))
```

results in :

0.119120892431

0.00010633951868

0.00214490709662

so the second method is fastest

Comment: The question states `A (4000,5), B (4000,4000),` and here you are using them flipped. Think you need to fix the question or this post.

Comment: Again, in the comments you said you are using NumPy matrices and you are using NumPy arrays here.